# Prescribing the acceleration of a curve.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, derivatives

For this question, I want to consider a smooth manifold $M$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$, having codimension one.

Given a curve $\alpha : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, if $\alpha$ happens to lie in $M$, meaning $\alpha(t) \in M$ for all $t$, then we have a restriction on its velocity, namely,

$$\alpha'(t) \in T_{\alpha(t)}M \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n.$$

**I am trying to figure out what would be the corresponding restriction on its *acceleration* $\alpha''(t)$.**

For this, I worked a few examples. For instance, if we take $M$ to be a linear hypersurface

$$M = \{ (0, x_2, \ldots, x_n) : x_i \in \mathbb{R} \} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n,$$

then it is clear that we must also have $\alpha''(t)$ tangent to $M$, since $\alpha(t) \in M$ implies $\alpha$ has first component zero.

On the other hand, if $M$ is a circle sitting inside $\mathbb{R}^2$, $\alpha''(t)$ can be *orthogonal* (in the Euclidean metric) to $M$. So my question is:

**Question:** For general $M$ as above, which vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be realized as accelerations of curves lying in $M$?

**Note that I do not want to consider the intrinsic acceleration, or covariant derivative, of $\alpha$; all quantities are computed in $\mathbb{R}^n$.**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $p\in M$, denote by $n_p$ the unit normal  to $M$ at $p$.
There is so called [second fundamental form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_fundamental_form) of $M$ at $p$;
let us denote it by $s_p$.

Then 
$$\langle \alpha''(t),n_{\alpha(t)}\rangle =s_{\alpha(t)}(\alpha'(t),\alpha'(t)).$$
This is the only restriction for $\alpha''(t)$.

In particular, if second fundamental form vanish at $\alpha(t)$ then $\alpha''(t)$ lies in the tangent plane $T_{\alpha(t)}$.

Comment: Thank you. I'm surprised that, unlike the case of the velocity, this doesn't give a linear subspace, unless of course $s_{\alpha(t)}$ vanishes.